# What is the range of `out` variable in a call to Rte_Read?

Tags: autosar

Assuming I have a call to the `Rte_Read` function of some element, I'm trying to understand what are the possibles the ranges of the `out` variable after this call, depending on the various constraints. I'm assuming that the return value of the call is always `RTE_E_OK` and no compuMethod.

If the associated `ApplicationDataType` of the variable has only a physical constraint, with `lowerLimit = 0` and `upperLimit = 10`, no constraint on the associated `ImplementationDataType` and a base type of `uint16`. Is the possible range for the `out` parameter `[0-10]` or `[0-65535]` ?

If the associated `ApplicationDataType` of the variable has an internal constraint, with `lowerLimit = 0` and `upperLimit = 10`, no constraint on the associated `ImplementationDataType` and a base type of `uint16`. Is the possible range for the `out` parameter `[0-10]` or `[0-65535]` ?

From my understanding of AUTOSAR_TPS_SoftwareComponentTemplate 5.2.4, the constraints of the `ImplementationDataType`s should always override (and be larger) the constraints of the `ApplicationDataType`s. Is it correct?

Comment: You should expect only values between 0 and 10 (inclusive) to be returned in a variable of type `unint16`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you would have to check about the supported RTE features of your Vendor.

In the AUTOSAR_SWS_RTE.pdf, there is the Return Value part of Rte_Read API, and there a link at the `RTE_E_INVALID` and `RTE_E_OUT_OF_RANGE`. When you follow this, you come to **chapter 4.3.8 Range Checks during Runtime**.

> 4.3.8 Range Checks during Runtime
>
> A software component might try to send a value that is outside the range that is specified at a dataElement or ISignal. In case of different ranges the result of a
> data conversion might also be a value that is out of range of the target representation.
> For a safe handling of these use cases the RTE provides range checks during runtime. For an overview see figure 4.46.
>
> **[SWS_Rte_08024]** Range checks during runtime shall occur after data invalidation, i.e. first the handleNeverReceived check, then the invalidation check and lastly the
> range check shall be effected.c(SRS_Rte_00180)
>
> ...
>
> **Range checks at receiver’s side**
>
> Range checks during runtime for intra ECU communication at the receiver’s side are described in the following requirements:
>
> **[SWS_Rte_08028]** dThe RTE shall implement a range check in the receiving path of a particular component if the handleOutOfRange is defined at the ReceiverComSpec
> and has any value other than none. In this case the range check applies only for data received by the particular component. c(SRS_Rte_00180)
>
> **[SWS_Rte_08041]** dThe RTE shall use the preceding limits **([SWS_Rte_07196])** from the DataPrototype in the rPort for the range check of received data in the receiving path of a particular component if the handleOutOfRange is defined at the ReceiverComSpec.c(SRS_Rte_00180)

Here it also refers to **SWS_Rte_07196** which specifies the precedence of the usage of DataConstrs (upper/lowerLimits).

Depending on the ReceiverComSpec's handleOutOfRange and handleOutOfRangeStatus it depends if you get out data with:

- last valid value
- no value
- saturated value (== upperLimit or lowerLimit)
- initValue or invalidValue

and you get either `RTE_E_OUT_OF_RANGE` or `RTE_E_INVALID` as return/error value.

The precedence requirement in ch 4.1.3 is as following:

> **[SWS_Rte_07196]** dThe RTE Generator shall respect the precedence of data properties defined via SwDataDefProps as defined in the Software Component Template [2].c()
>
> Requirement [SWS_Rte_07196] means that:
>
> 1. SwDataDefProps defined on ApplicationDataType which may be overwritten by
> 2. SwDataDefProps defined on ImplementationDataType which may be overwritten by
> 3. SwDataDefProps defined on AutosarDataPrototype which may be overwritten by
> 4. SwDataDefProps defined on InstantiationDataDefProps which may be overwritten by
> 5. SwDataDefProps defined on AccessPoint respectively Argument which may be overwritten by
> 6. SwDataDefProps defined on FlatInstanceDescriptor which may be overwritten by
> 7. SwDataDefProps defined on McDataInstance
>
> The SwDataDefProps defined on McDataInstance are not relevant for the RTE generation but rather the documentation of the generated RTE.
>
> **Especially the attributes** swAddrMethod, swCalibrationAccess, swImplPolicy and **dataConstr** do have an **impact on the generated RTE**. In the following document only the attribute names are mentioned with the semantic that this refers to the most significant one.

That means, if your ApplicationDataType has a DataConstr, but your ImplementationDataType has not, and also the following do not have it, then the ApplicationDataType DataConstr limits are used for the check. I read this as:

- if ApplicationDataType DataConstr = [0, 10] and
- if ImplememtationDataType DataConstr = (unset) and
- even the ImplementationDataType = uint16 with range [0,65535]

the range check will be done with [0,10].

Comment: So, you are assuming that the valid interval transfers 1:1 from `ApplicationDataType` to `ImplementationDataType` although no `CompuMethod` is specified?

Comment: I'm not really assuming but rather interpreting the precedence rrequirement. If there is no overwritten in 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and if in ImplDataType is also nothing overwritten/specifed as limits, then the ApplicationDataType's limits apply for range check, no matter if the uint16 can go up to 65535, or an uint32 goes up to 0xFFFFFFFFu.

Comment: The conversion between the value such as the upper and lower limit in an `ApplicationDataType` to the value in an `ImplementationDataType` depends on the existence of `CompuMethod`.